# Google calendar does not recognize iCalendar cancel request

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am testing a feature which involves creating and cancelling an invite.

`Google calendar` understand and can create a invite. However it cannot interpret my cancel request.

I tested the same request with `Yahoo Mail` and it works fine. I made sure than `UID` is same for create and cancel. Appreciate any help to understand what is wrong.

Create request:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR

BEGIN:VEVENT

UID:9da63b0c-0de9-4d48-a956-162587a71d15

DTSTAMP:20140104T163803

ORGANIZER;CN="jaikit savla":mailto:jkts...@gmail.com

DTSTART:20140113T020000

DTEND:20140113T030000

SUMMARY:party

METHOD:REQUEST

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Cancel request:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR

BEGIN:VEVENT

UID:9da63b0c-0de9-4d48-a956-162587a71d15

DTSTAMP:20140104T164034

ORGANIZER;CN="jaikit savla":mailto:jkts...@gmail.com

SUMMARY:party cancelled

METHOD:CANCEL

STATUS:CANCELLED

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

`METHOD` is a property of `VCALENDAR`, not `VEVENT`. You're also missing a ton of required properties. Try an iCalendar validator, this looks like it was written by hand rather than a library.

Answer (score 0):

I used somewhat same code for calender invitation.
But it was not storing calender invitation directly to calender.
I had to make it ad Add to calender.
Did you face this/such problem?